# Spacetime translation is not a gauge invariant symmetry in Maxwell's theory

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance

Consider the Action for Electromagnetism,

\begin{align}
I=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^4x\, F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu},
\end{align}

Suppose we perform a space-time translation, $x^{\mu} \to x^{\mu} + \epsilon ^{\mu}$ , we can write the variation in $A_{\mu}$ as the Lie Derivative.

$$\delta A_{\mu} = -\epsilon ^{\alpha} \partial _{\alpha} A_{\mu}$$

It is mentioned in [*"A short review on Noether's theorems, gauge symmetries and boundary terms"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03616) by Maximo Banados and I.A. Reyes in Page 22 that this is not a gauge invariant symmetry. I have a problem in this statement. Suppose you let $A_{\mu} \to A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} f $ .
Under a spacetime translation, $\delta f = -\epsilon ^{\alpha} \partial _{\alpha} f$ . So,

$$\delta (A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} f) = \delta A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(\delta f) \implies \delta (A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} f) = -\epsilon ^{\alpha} \partial _{\alpha} A_{\mu}  -\epsilon ^{\alpha} \partial_{\mu}\partial _{\alpha} f = -\epsilon ^{\alpha} \partial _{\alpha} (A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}f) $$

So,  $\delta (A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} f) = -\epsilon ^{\alpha} \partial _{\alpha} (A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}f) $ . which looks gauge invariant. I know that the conserved stress energy tensor obtained from this symmetry is not gauge invariant. I seem to be missing some detail here.

My question is, in what sense is the transformation not gauge invariant?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102442/discussion-on-question-by-abhikumbale-spacetime-translation-is-not-a-gauge-invar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression
$$ \delta(A_\mu) = \epsilon^\alpha\partial_\alpha A_\mu$$
is not gauge invariant in the usual, straightforward sense. Under a gauge transformation $A\mapsto A' = A +\mathrm{d}f$, it transforms exactly as you have shown,
$$ \delta A'_\mu =  \delta(A_\mu + \partial_\mu f) = \epsilon^\alpha\partial_\alpha(A_\mu + \partial_\mu f).$$
Were the expression gauge-invariant, we would have $\delta A' = \delta A$, which is clearly not the case.